# php echo single strand of elements multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am passing arrays from a product page and using the $_GET['id'] to store product ids in 'id' then storing it in session['items'].

On the cart page, I would like to echo out only the 'id' elements of the array and not the qty. But I still want to keep the current code where $item and $value are echo.

**Add-to-cart.php**

```
**code
session_start();

$_SESSION['items'][]=array(     
                            'id'=>"'".$_GET['id']."'",
                            'qty'=> 1                           
                        );  
?>
```

**Cart.php**

```
**code
<?php
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $items=>$values)
{
foreach($values as $item=>$value)
{
//// I want to keep this, 
    echo $item;

    echo $value."<br/>";
    echo "</br>";
//// I want to keep this  
//// echo 'id' values here!
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want `echo $value['id'];`

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $items=>$values)
{
foreach($values as $item=>$value)
{
//// I want to keep this, 
    echo $item;

    echo $value."<br/>";
    echo "</br>";
    //// I want to keep this  
    echo $value['id'];
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: What would `echo $value ` echo?

Comment: @Terminus I expect it would echo `Array`. Not my problem though, that's what the OP says he wants.

Comment: figured that. Thought it might do something I didn't know